# XML XSD Regular Expression Check

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like users to type in telephone number as below:

```
tel:+6411113100
```

i.e. the telphone number must start with `tel:+`

Could someone please show me how to apply the xsd validation to validate the above please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Michael Kay's answer above concerning sensible design. However, if you *really* want to restrict the value, here's an example of how you could do it:

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="telephoneNumber">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="tel:\+\d*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I would like users to type in telephone number as below: tel:+6411113100

I have to question whether this is a sensible design. For example, phone numbers are often presented with embedded spaces, and I can't see any good reason for preventing users entering the spaces if they wish. To put it another way, I would like to know what the users would like, not what you would like.

Comment: The requirement is that users must enter the telephone numbers as tel:+6411113100. This is why XSD is required to validate the schema. You have answer for this i.e. how to write XSD to achieve above??

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a "simple type" for the string. Restrict the type using 'string' as base (to capture also the tel:+ prefix) and use a `pattern` element to restrict to 'tel:+' followed by digits.